# Empy alert when passing a PHP variable to javascript (echo works)

Tags: javascript, php

**Context**

I am trying to pass a PHP variable to javascript.

**What I did**

I have the following function that is used to alert a PHP variable (here an array value)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validate(){
alert('<?php echo $array_temp[1]; ?>');
}
</script>
```

And the corresponding html.

```
<label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" id="Hypothesis Testing" name="Hypothesis Testing" onclick="validate()">Hypothesis Testing (3)</label>
```

It does not work. There is an alert but the content is empty.

If I simply do that (somewhere in my html document):

```
<?php echo $array_temp[1]; ?>
```

It outputs the content of the variable ($array_temp[1]).

**What I tried**

Many things :-( I played with ' and " and tried to json encode.

Comment: just put the javascript in your html document

Comment: Did the trick !!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

The best and recommended way to passing PHP variable (server language) to javascript is using rest API

**PHP code**

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');

echo json_encode($array_temp, JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_AMP);
```

with URL `/myapi/url`
Get it in ajax request with fetch, axios, ajax(jquery), ...

**Javascript**

```
fetch('/myapi/url').then(function(data){
 return data.json();
}).then(data => {
  alert(data);
})
```

Comment: While this aproach is correct, it does not answer the question. The trick is in the correct quoting, depending where the value is inserted. `json_encode` can escape apostrophes and keep raw quotes, it also can escape `<`, `>`, and `&` to not break HTML code. For example, if you want to insert a value directly into the HTML attribute, then enclose the attribute in apostrophes and use `JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_AMP` as the second parameter.

Comment: Won't forget `JSON_HEX_TAG` and `JSON_HEX_QUOT`.

Comment: `JSON_HEX_TAG` and `JSON_HEX_QUOT` are not necessary in HTML attribute value quoted by apostrophes. In fact, the use of apostrophes allows effective representation of the quotes and significantly reduces size of the objecs in JSON.